# give a lift to or without "to"?

Tags: grammar, verbs, particles

Reading a text I have seen the following:

> A man and two girls he gave a lift to.

But doesn't this mean that I can say "give a lift **to**"?

What about this:

> I gave my friend a lift.
>    I gave a lift to my friend.

Dictionary says "give sb a lift". But then I dont understand the "to" (A man who I gave a lift to - would not work without to?)

Comment: The second and third example have nothing to do with *lift* and everything to do with *give*. Check out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ditransitive_verb. The first example has little to do with anything as it stands, because it's incomplete. The *to* could be part of something else entirely. Quote the entire sentence.

Comment: Why should "give a lift to" be equivalent to "give lift to"? "A lift" is specific; "lift" is general. Why do you think you can say "give lift to"?

Comment: @Andrew Leach What? I am asking whether the following are equivavlent and correct: "give sb a lift" and "give a lift to sb"..

Comment: Your question says *But doesn't this mean that I can say "give lift to"?* and *A man who I gave lift to.* Not "**a** lift".

Comment: Oh right, this is just a typo, of course from the context is clear am I asking about the "to" as the dictionary states "give sb a lift" (speaking about the ride)

Comment: PoTros: you can't assume from the context that a missing article (a) is or isn't missing because it's a typo or because it's a different usage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question seems to be about the use of *to* and the differing word order when a verb such as *give* is followed by both a thing and someone who receives or benefits from it. As the examples show, two constructions are possible in such a situation. The recipient can be expressed as an indirect object, as in *I gave my friend a lift.* Alternatively, it can be expressed in a prepositional phrase, as in *I gave a lift to my friend.* In the latter case, the prepositional phrase follows the direct object. In the former case, the indirect object precedes the direct object.

Answer (score 2):

This is a classic transformation allowed in English for some verbs. You can say:

> I gave a book to her.

and

> I gave her a book.

They are equivalent in meaning (with different emphasis).

You cannot say 'I gave a book to.' all by itself; the preposition 'to' needs an object here. There are some verbs, called [phrasal verbs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrasal_verb) that have prepositions without objects.

Answer (score 0):

**A man who I gave a lift to** - *would not work without **to***?

Though the versions **with** *to* are far more common,  relative clauses and reduced relative clauses (where the *that*, *who* or *whom* etc is elided) may be used **with or without** the preposition *to*, corresponding to both variants of this 'dative transformation' (using this term as a syntactic label rather than examining the nature of *giving*) :

'A 59-year-old accused of raping a woman he gave a lift to has been ...'

'I know of one woman he gave a lift home from rural areas ...'

'The board also concluded his remarks to the boy he gave a lift “certainly appears to be ... " ' (all Google).

**ALSO**, one cannot simply say that 'a verb undergoes / does not undergo the dative transformation':

*Give* with its normal meaning certainly enters ditransitive constructions:

*He gave a heavy parcel to the woman.*

*He gave the woman a heavy parcel.* [ditransitive version]

So does *take*:

*He took a selection of magazines to his friend in hospital.*

*He took his friend a selection of magazines.*

[Even here, *He took his friend in hospital a selection of magazines* sounds clumsy.]

With different senses, perhaps involving more fossilised constructions,  one or other of the alternatives may not be considered grammatical:

*He gave her a withering look.* [*gave* is used delexically here]

**He gave a withering look to her.*

**He took the party a couple of bottles of wine.* [*took* is used in the sense *took along* here]

*He took a couple of bottles of wine to the party.*